# How to Determine Transaction Interface

Tags: extrinsic, transactions, metadata, versioning

In Substrate code, there is logic to determine the way in which extrinsics should be submitted to the runtime (ref: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/v3.0.0/client/transaction-pool/src/api.rs#L174). This logic is based on the version of Substrate's `TaggedTransactionQueue`. Does the version of the transaction queue line up with any of the versions that Substrate runtimes advertise via their [metadata](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/metadata/#decoded-metadata-format) (e.g. extrinsic version, metadata version)? What versions of Polkadot use which transaction versions?

It seems like maybe this should be advertised by way of [the `apis` attribute on the `RuntimeVersion` type](https://crates.parity.io/sp_version/struct.RuntimeVersion.html#structfield.apis), but I'm not sure how to decode the API ID.

Comment: The code you have linked in the transaction pool is not related in any way to the format of the extrinsic. This particular line is about backwards compatibility for the `TaggedTransactionQueue`, because there was added a new parameter for the `validate_transaction` function. For your other questions, I don't really get what you speak about? What version do you speak about or what format? Would be better if you could be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is communicated via [the `apis` attribute on the RuntimeVersion type](https://crates.parity.io/sp_version/struct.RuntimeVersion.html#structfield.apis). The interface version I am looking for is that of the `TaggedTransactionQueue`, which has an API ID of `0xd2bc9897eed08f15` per the [documentation](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_version/type.ApiId.html) for how to calculate these IDs.